# WordPress permalinks  Yahoo hosting(no .htaccess allowed) 

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I have moved a Wordpress install to a client from sub folder to the root folder. Right now, everything  works fine, except for the friendly URLs. I currently have to set the Permalink feature in "Common settings" to "Default", which means URLs with ?p=434... At least they work. Otherewise I get a very short 404 not found error message on a white screen. I was following [this](http://mwolk.com/blog/move-wordpress-blog-from-subfolder-to-root-folder/) tutorial, but I found I cannot write an .htaccess to my Yahoo host account and so I could not follow  one of the last steps... I wonder if the 404 not found errors have to do with this problem I have had uploading the .htaccess file... I currently do not have any .htaccess file up there... So maybe MOD_REWRITE is disabled... I have just ran phpinfo() and did not find any entry on mod_rewrite. Before moving the website, when it was still on a subfolder, the friendly URLs used to work, but now they don't. Has anyone came accross this experience and has successfully restablished the permalinks feature?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo doesn't allow users access to the htaccess file which means that you can't the mod_rewrite rules needed for custom permlinks.
The Only way around it that i've heard it works (never tried it myself) is to add /index.php/ to the beginning of your custom structure so:
Go to Permalink Settings > Select Custom Structure. And set the value as `/index.php/%postname%/`
or what ever you want as long as you add /index.php/ before it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, it works! Although the "index.php" isn't the most beautiful thing to be in the center of the URL, at least I have an option to the raw querystrings... Thank you.

Comment: Glad i Could help

Comment: Do you know anyone if .htaccess is not working then why the pretty url is working very well in sub folder of root if we set wordpress in sub folder of root. But when we will set the wordress on root then pretty or friendly url become not working. ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Yahoo Small Business Account Manager look for "Blog Manager".  There it will give you an opportunity to enter the new file path.  That should do it in most cases.

Do not deactivate or remove this plugin as it seems to be required by the WordPress Installation provided by the Yahoo Auto-installer.  In case you do, temporarily put up a secondary blog through the blog manager and copy the required files from the temporary plugin directory to your main blog directory.  When done simply use the Blog Manager to deactivate (remove) the temporary blog.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by going to the Yahoo control panel > Manage > Blog Manager

click "did your links change?"
click "update blog manager links", change the folder and hit "update"

go back into the wordpress control panel > settings > permalinks 
don't change anything, just hit "save changes"

and all my permalinks are working!

John

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Yahoo! WordPress automatic installer for your client's installation, you can also create custom permalinks for your account by going into your WordPress Dashboard > Appearance > Plugins section and activating the Customizable Permalinks plugin.

Please note: the Customizable Permalinks plugin assumes that the installation is still located in its initial directory. If you've moved the installation, or if you you didn't use the automatic installer, you might check the WordPress Plugins archive (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) for customizable permalink plugins that don't require .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up **custom error pages** use the `index.php` as 404 page. Now you can use regular permalinks on a single site installation.