# enable permalinks in window hosting

Tags: permalinks

I had been developing wordpress sites from last one year but never used window hosting but one of my client have window hosting. Apache module mod_rewrite in collaboration with .htaccess used to serve my purpose of Permalinks But in the window server I donot have any idea at all. I tried copying few xml in web.config but donot know where I am Wrong. I am on a sshared server with no access to Shell I want equivalent action of linux hosting in window hosting 1) Enable module_rewrite 2) Write .htaccess

Comment: I had refereed the question posted
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14539/wordpress-permalinks-yahoo-hostingno-htaccess-allowed
but the problem is now my plugin buddypress is not working

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to know which version of IIS running on the server. Old IIS did not have url re-write built-in and require third party module to function. New IIS have them built-in and some cases they also can load your .htaccess file for rules.

Make sure you have [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) installed and enabled.

Comment: by using `/index.php/%postname%/` in custom permalink structure, my permalinks are working, but plugin buddypress has stopped working.

Comment: IIS version that i am using on the server is Microsoft-IIS/6.0