# Can't view post, goes to 404 page. Please help

Tags: 404-error

I'm on a fresh install of WP and I just made a couple test posts. However, when I click on the post to view the 'single' page, it shows a 404. Furthermore, from the dashboard, when I go to the edit screen for that post and click on 'view post', I get the 404 page again. Any ideas on what can be wrong?

Comment: lots of things could be wrong - have you activated permalinks?

Comment: Yes, it is set to `/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: I just changed it back to the default permalinks and it worked. But then I changed it back to `/%category%/%postname%/` and it's not working again. Hmm...

Comment: can you post the contents of the .htaccess file in the root?

Comment: I also tried deactivating all of my plugins but no change unfortunately. Also, I just tried viewing a newly created page and it just goes to the home page but with the title of the page showing in the browser.

Comment: @ptriek Unfortunately, I have WP installed on a Yahoo Small Business hosting server which doesn't allow access to the .htaccess file. It's the weirdest thing ever. Every other hosting company I've ever dealt with allows access to the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're not the first one having this problem, you might want to check [WordPress permalinks  Yahoo hosting(no .htaccess allowed)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14539/wordpress-permalinks-yahoo-hostingno-htaccess-allowed)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Although having index.php in the middle of the url is pissing me off.